# WP Как создать кастомную форму оставления комментария для Reply комментариев

Tags: wordpress, комментарии

Есть кастомная форма оставления комментариев, в ней много дополнительных полей.

```
<?php
$post_id = get_the_ID();

?>

<div class="company-review-control">
    <div class="settings-form custom-checkbox custom-file">
        <?php

        add_action('comment_form_logged_in_after', 'extend_comment_custom_fields');
        add_action('comment_form_after_fields', 'extend_comment_custom_fields');
        function extend_comment_custom_fields()
        {

            echo '<div class="rating-label"><span>Product rating</span><div class="rating">';
            for ($i = 5; $i > 0; $i--) {
                echo '<input id="' . $i . '_star_product" class="rating-input" type="radio" name="rating_product"  value="' . $i . '"/><label for="' . $i . '_star_product" class="rating-star"></label>';
            }
            echo '</div></div>';

            echo '<div class="rating-label"><span>Service & Delivery</span><div class="rating">';
            for ($i = 5; $i > 0; $i--) {
                echo '<input id="' . $i . '_star_service" class="rating-input" type="radio" name="rating_service"  value="' . $i . '"/><label for="' . $i . '_star_service" class="rating-star"></label>';
            }
            echo '</div></div>';

            echo '<input id="rating_full" type="hidden" name="rating" value="0"/>';


            echo '<p class="comment-form-title">' .
                '<label for="title">' . __('Title of your review', 'am') . '</label>' .
                '<input id="comment_title" name="comment_title" type="text" placeholder="If you could say it in one sentence, what would you say?"/>';
            echo '</p>';


            echo '<label class="label_file label_file_upload"><span>' . __('Add your photo (optional)', 'am') . '</span><input type="file" name="file_upload" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg, .webp"></label>';

            echo '<label class="label_file label_file_proof"><span>' . __('Proof of purchase', 'am') . '</span><input type="file" name="file_proof" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg, .webp"></label>';

            echo '<label class="label_checkbox label_checkbox_confirm"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_confirm"><span class="checkmark"></span>
                    <span class="checkbox-txt">Eos tollit ancillae ea, lorem consulatu qui ne, eu eros eirmod scaevola sea. Et nec tantas accusamus salutatus, sit commodo veritus te, erat legere fabulas has ut. Rebum laudem cum ea, ius essent fuisset ut. Viderer petentium cu his.</span></label>';

            echo '<input type="hidden" name="comment_nonce" value="' . wp_create_nonce('comment_nonce') . '" />';
        }

        $comment_args = array(
            'comment_notes_before' => '',
            'logged_in_as' => '',
            'id_form' => 'comment_form_review',
            'id_submit' => 'submit',
            'class_container' => 'comment-respond',
            'class_form' => 'comment_form_review',
            'title_reply' => __('Write a review of ', 'am') . get_the_title(),
            'title_reply_to' => __('Write a review of %s ', 'am') . get_the_title(),
            'title_reply_before' => '<p id="reply-title" class="comment-reply-title h3">',
            'title_reply_after' => '</p>',

            'comment_notes_after' => '',

            'comment_field' => '<p class="comment-form_textarea">
                                <label for="comment"><span class="comment_title">' . _x('Your review', 'noun') . '</span></label>
                                <textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8"  aria-required="true" required="required" placeholder="Write your review to help others learn about this online business"></textarea>
                                </p>',
            'label_submit' => 'Save personal info',
            'submit_button' => '<input name="%1$s" type="submit" id="%2$s" class="%3$s" value="%4$s" />',
        );

        comment_form($comment_args);

        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Есть списов из этих комментариев, который имеет кнопки Ответить. По нажатию на которую под конкретным комментарием отображаеться данная форма в плачевном состоянии всё с теми же полями.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос - Как выводить другой вариант форми на этой же странице по нажатию Reply ?

```
<?php
                comment_reply_link(array(
                    'reply_text' => __('Reply', 'am'),
                    'depth'      => $depth,
                    'max_depth'  => $args['max_depth'],
                    'login_text' => __('Log in to Reply', 'am'),
                    'before' => '',
                ));
?>
```

Данную форму при отправке фильтруем таким хуком

```
// 2. Validation
add_filter('pre_comment_on_post', 'custom_verify_comment');
function custom_verify_comment($commentdata)
{


    if (empty($_POST['rating_product'])) {
        wp_die('Please select a product rating!');
    }

    if (empty($_POST['rating_service'])) {
        wp_die('Please select a service rating!');
    }

    // Проверка Nonce
    if (!isset($_POST['comment_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['comment_nonce'], 'comment_nonce')) {
        wp_die('Nonce verification failed!');
    }

    return $commentdata;
}
```

Comment: Делать свой попап. Создавать форму на php, выводить её с display: none, по клику на кнопку Reply показывать форму.

Comment: Ок, спасибо. Тогда ещё вопрос, а как разделить что б для НОВОЙ формы не применялись значения фильтрации из основной? Данный хук фильтрации я подключаю в 'functions.php' как его назначить на фильтрацию именно основной формы отправки комментарие, та что подключаеться через `<?php get_template_part('template-parts/write-review-block'); ?>` и не применять к форме без полей которых нету в наличии ? *Я пробовал данный блок держать вместе с template формой, но тогда валидация вообще не происходит...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для создания шаблона Ответов на комментария, действительно пришлось писать собственный шаблон в попап. Потом по нажатию кнопки Reply по id комментария забирать его данные, потом валидировать, а потом отсылать.

Вот так идет разделение валидации форм под разные темплейты

```
// 2. Validation
add_filter('pre_comment_on_post', 'custom_verify_comment');
function custom_verify_comment($commentdata)
{

    $is_review_template = is_page_template('template-parts/write-review-block.php');
    $is_reply_template = is_page_template('template-parts/write-review-reply-block.php');


    if ($is_review_template) {
//    if (empty($_POST['comment_title'])) {
//        wp_die('Please, write Title for message!');
//    }

        if (empty($_POST['rating_product'])) {
            wp_die('Please select a product rating!');
        }

        if (empty($_POST['rating_service'])) {
            wp_die('Please select a service rating!');
        }

        // Проверка Nonce
        if (!isset($_POST['comment_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['comment_nonce'], 'comment_nonce')) {
            wp_die('Nonce verification failed!');
        }

    }

    if ($is_reply_template) {
        // Проверка Nonce
        if (!isset($_POST['comment_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['comment_nonce'], 'comment_nonce')) {
            wp_die('Nonce verification failed!');
        }
    }

    return $commentdata;
}
```